# TFS ? - check in is not showing any changes

Tags: tfs, checkin

i initially downloaded code from TFS to a directory and then made a copy of that directory and made changes to the code in the copied directory, but when i copy the copy back to the original download directory, the check in is not showing any changes, so please let me know how i can get the new code back up to TFS?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a server workspace, then changes made outside the context of Visual Studio are not tracked -- you will have to check out the files you changed in order for it to pick up changes.

If you're using a local workspace (which are recommended and were introduced in TFS 2012), it should Just Work.

You are probably using a server workspace. You can [change a server workspace to a local workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=vsts) in your workspace management view.

See more on workspaces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=vsts